# Will this system of magnets rotate?

Tags: electromagnetism, rotational-dynamics, geomagnetism

A system of four magnets are placed as shown in the figure.

As per the application of Maglev, a stationary magnet produces electro motive force with the magnets in motion. 
Note That the point O is pivoted to the plane.
[image: The Representation Of System]

In that case will this system of magnets rotate.

Comment: If it would, it wouldn't for long.

Comment: Maybe if you changed the small bar magnets to alternating electromagnets... Oh, wait. That's a motor! :)